# Why docker executes commands on my server

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I wrote a docker file and i expect it to execute commands when i create a new container. While that is happening , it first executes on my server while creating the image.

Command used to create image

```
docker build -t myimage:latest .
```

Docker File

```
#FROM microsoft/nanoserver
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
MAINTAINER test@gmail.com
ADD ["files", "c:/files"]
RUN dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:iis-webserver /NoRestart
RUN dism /online /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIExtensions /NoRestart
RUN dism /online /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:IIS-ISAPIFilter /NoRestart
RUN dism /online /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET /NoRestart
RUN dism /online /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:IIS-CGI /NoRestart
RUN dism /online /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:IIS-CGI45 /NoRestart
```

What am i missing and how do i make sure the commands run only during docker instantiation.

Comment: What do you mean they are executed on your server? Those commands during build will be executed inside container and none of those will be executed on server. In addition to that use powershell and not DISM to install windows features

Answer (score 0):

If you want run commands when the docker container is created, you need to add this line to your Dockerfile

```
# replace 'python application.py' with whatever you need
CMD python application.py
```